# How do you display a neural network

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow

I'm new to tensorflow and ML but am progressing slowly. I know how to look at the weights and biases but am still trying to figure out if there is an easy way to display a neural network in the standard pictorial way. If anyone knows and could share I would be really grateful.

Comment: What would you like to visualize? Most papers just show the tensor dimensions (and maybe skip connections) and describe the activations of each layer. With Keras you can just call `model.summary()` in Python and it will show you the dimensions and layer types.

Comment: What would you gain by the visualization? The best visualization I have ever seen is the following: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JQ3hYko51Y

Answer (score 0):

**Is there an easy way to display a neural network in the standard pictorial way?**

Each deep learning package has **easy** and **pictorial** options for model visualization.  In TensorFlow, the following [model plotting utilities](https://keras.io/api/utils/model_plotting_utils/) are available:  `plot_model` and `model_to_dot`.